# Why I am getting "0" in front part of transforming digits into integer?

Tags: java

Example: when you type "1234567", it`s display "0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7". How can I rid of "0" in front part?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int num = 0;
    int eachNum = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your number here: ");
    num = input.nextInt();

    int num2 =  num;
    int length = String.valueOf(num).length();
    while ( length >= 0 ) {

        int substraction =(int) Math.pow(10, length);
        int sub = (int) substraction; 
            eachNum = num2 / sub % 10;
            System.out.print(eachNum + "\t");
            length--;

    }

}//end main method
```

Comment: You might want to start with `while( length > 0)`, i.e. for length = 7 you want to do 7 steps only.

Comment: Why taking all the trouble to calculate the individual digits when you already have a string representation from `String.valueOf(num)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first iteration.

`length` is `7`.

`pow(10, 7)` is `10,000,000` (I've put commas in for clarity).

`num2 / sub % 10;` is evaluated as `(num2 / sub) % 10` due to the *precedence* of `/` and `%` being the same so evaluation is from left to right.

This is `(1,234,567 / 10,000,000) % 10` which is `0 % 10` since *integer division* truncates the number. So your first output is `0`.

The simplest fix is probably to subtract 1 from the initial value of `length`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand my problem!

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this by doing:

```
while (length > 0) { // iterating one less time
    int substraction = (int) Math.pow(10, length-1); // length-1 to get from first digit
    ...
}
```

Anyway you can improve your code and do little trick even, so you don't need the calculations:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your number here: ");    
int num = input.nextInt();  

String str = String.valueOf(num);
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i)+"\t");
}
```

Comment: Ignore my last comment. This does work, and is probably a more tractable way than my proposal: upvoted.

Comment: Or, of course `System.out.println(String.valueOf(num).replaceAll(".", "$0\t"));`.

Comment: Or, don't need taking integer input at all. :P         `System.out.println(input.next().replaceAll(".", "$0\t"));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Now you will find your desire output

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int num = 0;
    int eachNum = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your number here: ");
    num = input.nextInt();

    int num2 =  num;
    int length = String.valueOf(num).length()-1;
    while ( length >= 0 ) {

        int substraction =(int) Math.pow(10, length);
        int sub = (int) substraction; 
            eachNum = (num2 / sub) % 10;
            System.out.print(eachNum + "\t");
            length--;

    }

}//end main
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also skip case when num2 < substraction. I try changing while in this way:

```
while ( length >= 0 ) {
    int substraction =(int) Math.pow(10, length--);
    int sub = (int) substraction; 

    if (num2 < substraction)
        continue;

    eachNum = num2 / sub % 10;
    System.out.print(eachNum + "\t");
}
```